# Calling C function by generic pointer

Tags: c, generics, function, pointers, call

Is there any method to call a function, by just knowing its address in a pointer, lets say a pointer of type `"void *(*)(void *)"`, and number and type of its parameter?

The function could have any number of parameters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not in any portable or standard way.

However, there is a standard way to pass a variable number of arguments between functions.  Have a look at `vsprintf`.  Basically, you need a version of the function that accepts a `va_list`.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, no.

You have to know the number of parameters before you can write the call, and therefore the types too.  Therefore, you cannot write one line of code that accurately calls a function that takes 0 parameters or 1 parameter or 2 parameters.  You could always provide 2 and trust things will work - but the compiler will (justifiably) give warnings.